# Comparing two tables using flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: sql, python-2.7, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm starting my adventure with python and flask.

I'm using Flask-SQLAlchemy for MySQL/MariaDB task

```
class Local(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'local'
    id = db.Column("VideoLocalID", db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    file_path = db.Column("FilePath", db.String)
    hash = db.Column("Hash", db.String)

class Remote(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'remote'
    id = db.Column("EpisodeID", db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    # hash = db.relationship('Local', backref='hash', lazy='dynamic')
    hash = db.Column("Hash", db.String)
    #hash = db.relationship(db.String, db.ForeignKey('local.hash'))
    percentage = db.Column("Percentage", db.Integer)
```

I'm trying to get all the items that don't "hash" don't exist in both tables. I'm interested only in items that are in Local table.

Like you see I tried to make FK work but without success

```
localv = Local.query.all()
remotev = Remote.query.all()
    for video in localv:
        for video_remote in remotev:
            #checking if there is a match if not adding to list
```

I think that my double for loop is bad. Is there a way to speed this up, or even make it do in database instead of local?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most succinct way to do that is

```
# get all rows with distinct (unique) hashes from Remote and create a list of hashes.
remote_hash_list = [item.hash for item in Remote.query.distinct(Remote.hash).all()]

# Now get all Local items that hash is not in remote hashes list
local_items = Local.query.filter(Local.hash.notin_(remote_hash_list)).all()
```

Comment: Sir, you made my day. Thank you Wizard